# call transferFocus or requestFocus?

Tags: java, swing, focus

in my application i get a component to focus , 
it could be a jpanel , and is could be a jbutton or a user custom made component

how can i know when to call transferFosus ,and when to call requestFocus

thanks you

Comment: the code to request focus , 
should know what method to call 
it can be a JPanel with some buttons inside (transferFocus)
or just a JButton (requestFocusInWindow)
what method should i call when i know i get a JComponenet

Comment: what i did for now was 



if(dCompoenet instanceof AbstractButton){
  dCompoenet.requestFocusInWindow();
}else{
  dCompoenet.transferFocus();  
}


what do u think ?

Answer (score 3):

`transferFocus()` sends focus to the next component. **Also note** that 
`transferFocus()` will always transfer the focus in the forward direction.

`requestFocus()` sends focus to calling component. However, there is no guarantee that this will be successful. Focus behavior is platform-dependent to certain extend.

The **recommended** mentod for gaining focus is to use `requestFocusInWindow()`. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167760/java-textfield-focus) - might come very handy in playing with focus.

Comment: so i get a jcompoenent and i need to deside 
what to call 
transferFocus 
or
requestFocusInWindow

i know i will cal 'requestFocusInWindow' for a jbutton
and 'transferFocus' for a jpanel that holds buttons inside it 

by what i can decide what method to call

Answer (score 1):

Use transferFocus() when you want to advance focus according to the focus order.
requestFocus() is used to explicitly set the focus to a component.

Some background reading in [Focus on Swing](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-1998/jw-07-swing-focus.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's rare that you would need to call either since its usually appropriate to let the user's keyboard/mouse actions determine focus.  But transferFocus send focus away from your component and requestFocus brings focus to your component.