# Java JTextfield focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield

I made an application, which got quite alot textfields, which clear text on focus. When i run the application, the application works abolutely fine. Then, i made a menu, which give me a choice to open the application, or open the txt my FileWriter wrote. Now, when i run application using menu, it focuses on the first textfield. How do i make the menu run the application without focus on first textfield?? as i said, when i run application without menu, it doesnt focus.. hope u can help! 
         Best Regards, Oliver.

Menu:

```
public class menu extends JFrame{

    private JFrame fr;
    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;

    private JPanel pa;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new menu();

    }

    public menu(){
        gui();
    }
    public void gui(){

        fr = new JFrame("menu");
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setSize(200,63);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        pa = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        b1 = new JButton("Infostore");
        b2 = new JButton("log");

        pa.add(b1);
        pa.add(b2);
        fr.add(pa);

        Eventhandler eh = new Eventhandler();
        b1.addActionListener(eh);
        b2.addActionListener(eh);
    }
    private class Eventhandler implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){


            if(event.getSource()==b1){
                IS is = new IS();
                fr.setVisible(false);
            }

            if(event.getSource()==b2){

                try{
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad C:\\Applications\\Infostore.txt");
                    }catch(IOException ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                System.exit(1);

            }


        }

    }
}
```

Application:

```
public class IS extends JFrame{

    private JLabel fname;
    private JTextField name;
    private JTextField lname;
    private JLabel birth;
    private JTextField date;
    private JTextField month;
    private JTextField year;
    private JTextField age;
    private JButton cont;
    private JLabel lcon;
    private JTextField email;
    private JTextField numb;

    String inumb;

    int[] check = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int sum=0;

    private JPanel p;
    private JFrame f;


    public static void main(String[] args){
        new IS();
                }


    public IS(){
        gui();
    }

    public void gui(){

        f = new JFrame("Infostore");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(200,340);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        p = new JPanel();
        fname = new JLabel("Name    ");
        name = new JTextField("Name",12);
        lname = new JTextField("Last name",12);
        birth = new JLabel("Birthday");
        date = new JTextField("Date",12);
        month = new JTextField("Month",12);
        year = new JTextField("Year",12);
        age = new JTextField("Your age",12);
        lcon = new JLabel("Contact");
        email = new JTextField("E-mail",12);
        numb = new JTextField("Phone (optional)",12);
        cont = new JButton("Store Information");

        p.add(fname);
        p.add(name);
        p.add(lname);
        p.add(birth);
        p.add(date);
        p.add(month);
        p.add(year);
        p.add(age);
        p.add(lcon);
        p.add(email);
        p.add(numb);
        p.add(cont);


        f.add(p);


        f.setVisible(true);

        name.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {             
                String jname = name.getText();
                if(jname.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
                    name.setText("");
                }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String jname = name.getText();
                if(jname.equals("")){
                    name.setText("Name");
                    check[0] = 0;
                }else{
                    check[0] = 1;
                }
            }});

        lname.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {             
                String jlname = lname.getText();
                if(jlname.equalsIgnoreCase("last name")){
                lname.setText("");
                }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String jlname = lname.getText();
                if(jlname.equals("")){
                    lname.setText("Last name");
                    check[1] = 0;
                }else{
                    check[1] = 1;
                }
                }});

        date.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {             
                String jdate = date.getText();
                if(jdate.equalsIgnoreCase("date")){
                    date.setText("");
                }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String jdate = date.getText();
                if(jdate.equals("")){
                    date.setText("Date");
                    check[2] = 0;
                }else{
                    check[2] = 1;
                }
                }});

        month.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {             
                String jmonth = month.getText();
                if(jmonth.equalsIgnoreCase("month")){
                    month.setText("");
                }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String jmonth = month.getText();
                if(jmonth.equals("")){
                    month.setText("Month");
                    check[3] = 0;
                }else{
                    check[3]=1;
                }
                }});

        year.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {             
                String jyear = year.getText();
                if(jyear.equalsIgnoreCase("year")){
                    year.setText("");
                }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String jyear = year.getText();
                if(jyear.equals("")){
                    year.setText("Year");
                    check[4] = 0;
                }else{
                    check[4] = 1;
                }
                }});

        age.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {             
                String jage = age.getText();
                if(jage.equalsIgnoreCase("your age")){
                    age.setText("");
                }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String jage = age.getText();
                if(jage.equals("")){
                    age.setText("Your age");
                    check[5] = 0;
                }else{
                    check[5] = 1;
                }
                }});

        email.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {             
                String jemail = email.getText();
                if(jemail.equalsIgnoreCase("e-mail")){
                    email.setText("");
                }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String jemail = email.getText();
                if(jemail.equals("")){
                    email.setText("E-mail");
                    check[6]=0;
                    }else{
                        check[6]=1;
                    }
                }});

        numb.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {             
                String jnumb = numb.getText();
                if(jnumb.equalsIgnoreCase("phone (optional)")){
                    numb.setText("");
                }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String jnumb = numb.getText();
                if(jnumb.equals("")){
                    numb.setText("Phone (optional)");
                    }else{
                    }
                }
            });



        eventh eh = new eventh();
        cont.addActionListener(eh);
       }


    private class eventh implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            sum = check[0] + check[1] + check[2] + check[3] + check[4] + check[5] + check[6];

            if(event.getSource()==cont&&sum==7){
                String sname = name.getText();
                String slname = lname.getText();
                String sdate = date.getText();
                String smonth = month.getText();
                String syear = year.getText();
                String sage = age.getText();
                String semail = email.getText();
                String snumb = numb.getText();

                if(snumb.equalsIgnoreCase("Phone (optional)")){
                    numb.setText("");
                }

                String inumb = ("Phone: "+numb.getText());

                String info = ("Name:  "+sname+" "+slname+" "+"Birthday: "+sdate+"-"+smonth+"-"+syear+" "+" Age:"+sage+"  "+"E-mail:"+" "+ semail+"  "+inumb);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,info);

                filewriter fw = new filewriter();
                fw.setName(info);
                fw.writeFile();

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(150);
                }catch(InterruptedException ex){
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                System.exit(0);

                    }else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please fill out all fields");
                    }


            }
    }





    }
```

Comment: what does the `filewriter` refer to here? is that a built in function? I mean isn't it `FileWriter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must force all the parents of the textfield to get focus, then we can set focus on the textfield

[Java Textfield focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167760/java-textfield-focus)